# Start select option from highest to lowest

Tags: php

How would I start the selection from 50 going down?

```
$i_season=1; $i_season<=50; $i_season++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i_season=50; $i_season>=1; $i_season--
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<?php 

    for($i_season=50; $i_season>=1; $i_season--)
    {
        // to write your code
        echo $i_season;
    }
?>
```

Or Also try below code

```
<?php 

    $i_season=50;
    while($i_season!= 0)
    {
        // to write your code
        echo $i_season;
        $i_season--;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the two versions

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it an alternative way (slower)

```
<?php 
$seasons = range(50,1);

foreach ($seasons as $season) {
    echo $season."<br/>";
}
?>
```